# Facebook sharing: image & description not (always) displayed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use the usual Facebook tags on my blog to make sure that a title, image and description are displayed when sharing pages. I've been using this for a long time without paying much attention to it but I recently discovered that images and sometimes descriptions were not displayed anymore.

Here is a code example:

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.laurentwillen.be/gadgets/test-avis-projecteurs/xiaomi-wanbo-x1-test-avis/" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Xiaomi Wanbo X1 : test / avis (avec code promo -30%)" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="J'ai testé le Xiaomi Wanbo X1 sur de nombreux critères objectifs (qualité image, son, compatibilité netflix, ...) et je l'ai comparé aux autres projecteurs." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2021/07/wanbo-x1-test-avis-review-opiniones-recensione-erfahrung-bewertung-top.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1500"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="468"/>
```

When I test this page in the Facebook debugger, outside the fb:app_id I don't get any error message but I can't see the image:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

For this second example, the image is not working but the description also never shows up (while tags are the same)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Aidez-moi (klintistwood) à gagner le Robot Aspirateur Lefant M210s" />
<meta property="og:description" content="J'aimerais gagner le robot aspirateur Lefant M210s et vous pouvez m'aider sans devoir faire un don d'organe." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://contest.laurentwillen.be/?c=3&p=8145ed4714f0159fc801d41037d53903" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1500"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="468"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://10jtal.be/cms/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2021/07/lefant-m210s-test-review-avis-recensione-prueba-opinion-beoordeling-28-scaled.jpg" />
```

I've read multiple posts about this, in some cases it was just a caching issue but it doesn't seem to be my case because images never show up and sometimes descriptions don't show up.

I have also tried to use og:image:secure but it didn't help.
Copy/pasting the image link directly to Facebook also doesn't work but there are no restrictions on my server that could explain this.

Any idea?

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzRe2.png

Comment: Just made a test post using your second URL, and everything shows absolutely fine. If the debug tool doesn't give you any errors, then I don't think there is anything you can fix about this from your end.

Comment: @CBroe thanks! If I'm the only one not seeing it, it's strange but I can live with it. I'll see if others are saying the same and if yes, it means there is no issue. Thanks!